# The fastest and most efficient way to find the number of distinct elements of a 1D array

Tags: arrays, c, malloc

So I'm very new to programming and the C language, and I would like to find the simplest, fastest, and most efficient way to count all the distinct elements of a 1D array. This was actually for a school assignment, but I've been stuck on this problem for days, since my program was apparently too slow for the online judge and it got a TLE. I've used regular arrays and dynamically allocated arrays using malloc, but neither worked.

Anyways, here's the latest code of it(using malloc):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int distinct(int *arr, int N){
    
    int j, k, count = 1;
    
    for(j = 1; j < N; j++){
        for(k = 0; k < j; k++){
            if(arr[j] == arr[k]){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(j == k){
            count++;
        }
    }
    
    return count;
}

int main(){
    
    int T, N, i = 0;
    
    scanf("%d", &T);
    
    do{
        scanf("%d", &N);
        int *arr;
        arr = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            scanf("%d", &arr[j]);
        }
        int count = distinct(arr, N);
        printf("Case #%d: %d\n", i + 1, count);
        i++;
    }while(i < T);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sort the array and check if there are two identical consecutive elements

Comment: *So I'm very new to programming and the C language*  Then don't worry at all about finding "[t]he fastest and most efficient way" to do anything. Learn how to write code that's both readable and maintainable so when you see the code you wrote again in two weeks you don't have to spend 30 minutes figuring out what the idiot who wrote it was trying to do.

Comment: How large values do you allow, can an `int` hold any value or can they be restricted to a certain range?

Comment: _The_ fastest implementation would indeed depend a lot on what specific system and compiler you are using.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I mean, the reason why I'm trying to find the fastest and most efficient way to do it was because the online judge said that it's still too slow. So yeah, I know I'm pretty stupid for asking about this, but my curiosity is killing me.

Comment: @Lundin The maximum size of the array is 10^6, if that's what you're wondering.

Comment: No, as I wrote, what values do you allow the array to contain? If they were restricted to lets say 0 to 100 for example, you could make a table of counters where the index corresponds to a certain value encounter. But if they can be any value to +/- 2^31 then such a solution isn't feasible.

Comment: Your actual goal is not to find the fastest way. That is difficult and depends on the processor architecture and features and other factors. Your actual goal is to make the program fast enough to satisfy the online judge. The method for that is likely simple: Sort the array. That will put identical elements next to each other. Then look through the array checking whether any two adjacent elements are identical. The sort should be O(n log n), meaning the number of steps it takes is proportional to n times log n, where n is the number of elements in the array…

Comment: … If you have not learned to write an efficient sort or to call a library routine that performs a sort, then you are not ready to work on this problem. To prepare, you must learn that.

Comment: you could create 2 arrays and, when you archive the data, in the first array you save the data and in the second, the relative counter at the same index. When you need to store new data, first you look for it in the first array and if you find it you increase the counter in the second array at the same index, otherwise you insert it and put its counter which will be worth 1 in the second array at the same index (position). When you have to do the search you will have the first array that contains every single value and in the second array and at the same index the relative occurrences.

Comment: The other solution is to build a hahstable, which is O(n). Or, if your machine is good at factoring into prime numbers: compute the product of prime(i) for all numbers i, and find the number of distinct prime divisors of this product.

Comment: @Drakonus Did you try what I put in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The *most efficient way* depends on too many unknown factors. One way is to sort the array and then to count distinct elements in there, skipping the duplicates as you go. If you have sorted the array and gotten this:

```
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3
^       ^       ^
+-skip--+-skip--+-- end
```

... you can easily see that there are 3 distinct values in there.

If you don't have a favourite sorting algorithm handy, you could use the built-in [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) function:

```c
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
           int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compar(const void *l, const void *r) {
    const int* lhs = l;
    const int* rhs = r;
    if(*lhs < *rhs) return -1; // left side is less than right side: -1
    if(*lhs > *rhs) return 1;  // left side is greater than right side: 1
    return 0;                  // they are equal: 0
}

int distinct(int arr[], int N){
    // sort the numbers
    qsort(arr, N, sizeof *arr, compar);

    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < N; ++count) {
        int curr = arr[i];
        // skip all numbers equal to curr as shown in the graph above:
        for(++i; i < N; ++i) {
            if(arr[i] != curr) break;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    int T, N, i = 0;
    
    if(scanf("%d", &T) != 1) return 1; // check for errors
    
    while(T-- > 0) { 
        if(scanf("%d", &N) != 1) return 1;

        int *arr = malloc(N * sizeof *arr);
        if(arr == NULL) return 1; // check for errors

        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            if(scanf("%d", &arr[j]) != 1) return 1;
        }

        int count = distinct(arr, N);

        free(arr); // free after use

        printf("Case #%d: %d\n", ++i, count);
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(++i; i < N; ++i)` gave me an allergic reaction :) How about `for(int j=i+1; j<N; j++)` ... `arr[j]`?

Comment: @Lundin :-D Well, that would mean I have to declare `j` outside of the loop and assign `i` to it afterwards. `int j = i + 1; for(;j<N; ++j) {...} i = j;` - Not sure that becomes clearer. It's the `i` index I want to skip forward until a new number is encountered and I want the next iteration of the outer loop to use that `i`